# Multiple classes in one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This has been wreaking my head all day and before I give up I thought I'd see if anyone could help me out.

I have a sticky header that moves down the page when scrolled. I'm using bootstrap and have two classes in one div -  `navbar` for the regular view and `navbarSticky` for the sticky effect when scrolled.

The problem is when I have both classes in the div, the `navbar` class completely disappears but `navbarSticky` works and `navbar` will only return when the `navbarSticky` class is deleted from the div. I was thinking it must have something to do with CSS - `navbarSticky` having more precedence over `navbar`.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out.

This is my navbar :

```
<div class="navbar navbarSticky navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="logo col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                <ul class="pull-left">
                    <li><a href="">Theme</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="nav col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                <ul class="pull-right">
                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Products</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Example Dropdown</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Example Dropdown</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Example Dropdown</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Example Dropdown</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Join</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-button col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                <ul class="pull-right">
                    <li>
                        <button id="menu-button" type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="nav-dropdown" class="nav-dropdown col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <ul>
            <li id="form">
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Products</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Example Dropdown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Example Dropdown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Example Dropdown</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Example Dropdown</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Join</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function (){

if($(window).scrollTop() > 65)
{
    $("navbar").addClass('navbarSticky');
    $(".navbarSticky").css({
        'display':'block'
    })
}
else{
    $("navbar").removeClass('navbarSticky');
    $(".navbarSticky").css({
        display:'none'
    })
}
});
```

This is my css

```
.navbar
{
background: #ffffff;
color: #2d3238;
position: relative;
-webkit-transition: all 1s;
-moz-transition: all 1s;
-ms-transition: all 1s;
-o-transition: all 1s;
transition: all 1s;
height: 100px;
}
.navbarSticky
{
background: #ffffff;
box-shadow: 1px 5px 15px #ccc;
color: #2d3238;
display: none;
top: 0;
height: 100px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
position: fixed;
-webkit-transition: all 1s;
-moz-transition: all 1s;
-ms-transition: all 1s;
-o-transition: all 1s;
transition: all 1s;
z-index: 9999;
}
```

Update:

I Finally have it working, i just needed to change navbar in jquery to .navbar but now i have some wierd jumping down effect of the navbarSticky when it crosses over from the navbar. Could someone help?

Comment: Could you put your code into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? It makes it much easier for people to see what the problem is.

Comment: Have you tried leaving navbarsticky out of the initial html? It shouldn't be there until you scroll down for the first time, right?

Comment: Why not just use position: fixed on the navbar? Or, since you're using Bootstrap, use the classes "navbar navbar-fixed-top". Does it not sit at the top of the screen initially?

Comment: First of all, you don't need to repeat css rules. If you at all times have `.navbar` class on the element you don't need to rewrite background etc. in `navbarSticky`. Secondly I think you should reconsider your code a bit. Currently I'm thinking first of all making the navbar always fixed. If that works, You can add the javascript to make it disappear/appear on scroll. And you do that by adding or removing a class (for example: `.hidden`, which would pretty much be something like `.hidden {top: -100px;}`)

Answer (score 0):

`navbarSticky` overwrites every property on `navbar`.  It isn't that the `navbar` class disappears, it is that none of it's own css properties dominate so you see none of it until the dominating `navbarSticky` class has been removed.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response guys. I have a topbar above the navbar so using position: fixed would not work. i have tried leaving navbarSticky ouit of the html but that doesnt work either, im just running out of ideas lol its driving me crazy i think i have spent too long on it that my brains fried lol. When i use seperate divs it works but thats alot of styling and code that i was hoping i could avoid by using the same div